# Building Boost 1.49 on Windows 7

Tags: windows, gcc, boost

I'm trying to build Boost on Windows. I used [this](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3aF-SjKkzNSbIJ%3afw-geekycoder.blogspot.com/2010/12/building-boost-using-mingw.html%20building%20boost%20mingw&cd=11&hl=bg&ct=clnk&gl=bg) example. So, after executing 'bjam toolset=gcc' i'm getting the following errors:

```
**C:/boost/tools/build/v2/tools\gcc.jam:129: in gcc.init from module gcc
error: toolset gcc initialization:
error: no command provided, default command 'g++' not found
error: initialized from
C:/boost/tools/build/v2/build\toolset.jam:38: in toolset.using from module tools
et
C:/boost/tools/build/v2\build-system.jam:481: in process-explicit-toolset-reques
ts from module build-system
C:/boost/tools/build/v2\build-system.jam:562: in load from module build-system
C:\boost\tools\build\v2/kernel\modules.jam:283: in import from module modules
C:\boost\tools\build\v2\kernel\bootstrap.jam:142: in boost-build from module
C:\boost\boost-build.jam:17: in module scope from module**
```

How to compile that thing on Windows? Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: Can you run `g++` from the command line?

Comment: Yes, i can. No problem with that.

Comment: There is a guide supplied with boost itself. Maybe it's worth looking at?

Comment: So, just to be clear: `g++.exe` is in the PATH environment variable (you're not running g++  by specifying the full path on the command line or there's no `g++.cmd` or `.bat` instead of `g++.exe` on the path)?

Comment: Have you tried `bootstrap.bat gcc` ànd then `.\b2 --toolset=gcc` in the boost root directory? I guess youre using mingw so check that the path to the `mingw\bin` folder is stored in the path environment variable

Answer (score 2):

I needed a line like:

```
using gcc : 4.7 : g++-4.7 ;
```

in my user-config.jam file (found in C:\Users\USER_NAME\user-config.jam).

Can you run the program g++-4.7 (or your version number here) from the default command line (without modifying the PATH variable)?

Comment: Thank you!  I had to do this on the current Debian.